# Size of the intersection of two random binary trees.

Tags: combinatorics, probability-theory, trees

I am working on a problem that requests to analyze the size of the intersection of two binary trees which are chosen independently and uniformly at random.

Formally speaking, consider an underlying complete binary tree $\text{CBT} = (V, E)$ of nodes $|V| = N = 2^L - 1$ (i.e., $L$ height in total) with root node $v_r \in V$. Given $n \leq N$, let
\begin{equation}
\mathcal{T}_{n} := \{T ~ \text{binary subtree in $\text{CBT}$} ~|~ T ~ \text{rooted at $v_r$},~ |T| = n\}
\end{equation}
be the set of subtrees of size $n$ in $\text{CBT}$ with root node $v_r$. Uniformly and independently pick two subtrees $T, T' \in \mathcal{T}_{n}$ at random. The target is to compute **the probability of the size of the intersection of these two random binary trees $T, T'$**, i.e.,
\begin{equation}
\mathbb{P}_{T, T' \sim \text{Uni}[\mathcal{T}_n]} (|T \cap T'| = s), ~~~~ \text{for any $s \leq n$.} 
\end{equation}

My previous idea of computing this probability is by counting the number of binary trees $T$ which intersects with a given/fixed binary tree $T_*$ on $s$ nodes. One related paper is http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/download?doi=10.1.1.722.412&rep=rep1&type=pdf which (eq. 2.38) provides an asymptotic expansion on the number of subtrees with nodes $k$ and height $h$. However, for different choices of $T_*$, the number of binary trees $T$ that satisfies $|T \cap T_*| = s$ is very different. The above paper is not sufficient to answer my question.

Comment: What did you try?  $L=10, n=5$?

Comment: Hi Markvs, actually I would like to obtain an explicit form (very unlikely) or an upper bound on the above probability based on $N, L, n, s$.

Comment: The question would attract positive responses if you include info about the motivation and your efforts in the question. Otherwise the question may be closed as having no context. Eventually the question will be deleted together with all answers.

Comment: Got it, thanks for your comments. Will add them soon.